# Characteristic Polynomial Question

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a question that I encountered: to find a polyomial $g(t)$ such that linear map $g(T)$ has characteristic polynomial $p(t) = (11-t)^r(17-t)^{n-r}$

Obviously the eigenvalues are $11$ and $17$ the matrix of $g(T)$ has $11$ and $17$ on the diagonals with their respective multiplicities. But it is not very clear to me what is means to find a polynomial $g(t)$?

Comment: In your question, $T$ is given, or arbitrary?

Comment: I guess you were also given a $T$, because if you can choose both $T$ and the polynomial $g$, then the second becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, what if T is given as an orthogonal projection?

Comment: @mathnoob Can you please add to your question what is $T$ what is $n$ and what is $r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if $T$ is an orthogonal projection $T \ne 0, I$, and you choose a basis so that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
&1\\
&&\dots\\
&&&1\\
&&&&0\\
&&&&&0\\
&&&&&&\dots\\
&&&&&&&0\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where blanks denote zeroes, and there are $r$ ones and $n-r$ zeroes on the diagonal, then take
$$g(t) = 11 t + 17 (1-t).$$

Comment: But then you assume that $r$ is the rank, don't you?

Comment: @LiorB-S, yes. I could also exchange the roles of $r$ and $n-r$ using $g(t) = 17 t + 11 (1-t)$.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the OP question...

Comment: As I understand it, it says the following. Suppose $T = T^2$ is a projection different from $0, I$. (This is in the comments.) Show that there is a polynomial $g(t)$ such that the characteristic polynomial of $g(T)$ is of the form $(11-t)^r(17-t)^{n-r}$ for some $r$. (Here $n$ has to be the dimension of the underlying space.)

Answer (score 0):

c This is not possible in general. For example if $T=0$ is the transformation that sends every vector to the zero vector, then $g(T)=c \cdot {\rm id}$, for any polynomial $g$. Hence $p(t)=(t-c)^n$ (assuming $n$ denotes the dimension of vector space on which $g$ is defined).